# Copying and pasting(using right-click copy and paste menu) a cell with a user defined function inside changes all cells with udfs to #N/A

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

Greetings stackoverflow community!

I have an excel macro-enabled workbook that contains a fair amount of user defined functions. In excel 2016, while I select a cell with =UDFNAME(param1;param2) and try to copy its contents via right-click copy and then paste(first option in the menu) into a lower cell in the same column, every single sell that calls has a udf inside (=UDFNAMEWHATEVER(param1;param2)) turns #N/A on me. Refresh all and recalculate manually does not work. To my knowledge, all udfs have an Application.Volatile statement.

If I try to reevaluate every single cell individually, then the value of the cell will appear again.

Any kind of help will be very appreciated.

Comment: It will be difficult to solve this without seeing your code.

Comment: you can try force recalculate with Ctrl + Shift + Alt + F9 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx

Comment: I tried to force excel to recalculate the entire wb with  Ctrl + Shift + Alt + F9 and it worked. The situation itself is a bit awkward. Thank you very much Slai!

Comment: I had issues with this awhile back, but unfortunately I never got a resolution either.

Comment: I've opened the workbook in excel 2010 and saved it. Afterwards excel 2016 somehow managed to recalculate every udf harmoniously.